# can i change an alarn to a repeating alarm?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

how can i change an allreaddy set alarm to a repeating alarm?
i set the alarm with the `AlarmManager`?
My actual code looks like this:

```
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, intervall, pendingIntent);
```

thanks for helping, 
Florian

edit: i solved my problem in a other way(setting a new alarm every time), so no stress, but i am stil wondering how this would work

Comment: You can cancel the old alarm and set the new one.

Comment: Ok, thank you verry much, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done this job by Service class.

For example

In the `Application's onCreate()` method, you have to initialize the `AlarmManager` like below.

```
long l = 60000;
try {

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncBroadcastReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, SYNC_CALL_TO_SERVER_PENDING_INTENT,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), l, pendingIntent);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

And `SyncBroadcastReceiver` like,

```
public class SyncBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            //comment to check crash
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ServiceClass.class);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(intent1);
            } else {
                context.startService(intent1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

And ServiceClass like

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {
     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         // hitNotification(); // what need to act like notification dialog
         return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```